# logical proposition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have a question about the following proposition as argument, I need to get to an argument that has no number, from 1-2-3 premises. derived:
$$
\begin{align}
&(P \vee Q)\vee M \\
& R\supset S \tag{1} \\
& (P\equiv M) \,\&\,  ( P\vee (R\vee M)) \tag{2} \\
& S\supset \,\sim\! R \tag{3} \\
\end{align}
$$

I appreciate any cooperation

Comment: And your question is... what? Are you attempting to derive one statement from the others?? Which, the first? (It's unnumbered, unlike the rest.) (1) and (3) together imply $\sim\!R$. // The last, (3), does not follow from the others: take $P, M, R, S$ all true.  // But I really don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I need to get to an argument that has no number, from 1-2-3 premises.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: &(P \vee Q)\vee M \\

Comment: What's your language, and what are the axioms? There are things like $\sim$ which are ambiguous without clarification.

Comment: @user76838 You statement makes no sense. & would never be a governing logical operator.

Answer (score 3):

Outline of deduction:

- From (1) and (3), $R \to \neg R$, which is equivalent to $\neg R \vee \neg R$, which is to say, $\neg R$.
- From (2), $P \vee (R \vee M)$, so $P \vee M$ (because not $R$).
- From this, it follows that $(P \vee Q) \vee M$, as $P \to (P \vee Q)$.

*Note that the equivalence $P \equiv M$ wasn't used.*